How to make ring-bell in a pc without pc speaker?
Some modern pc motherboards don't have pc speaker.
In my case
sudo modprobe pcspkr

module load but I cannot see any changes in dev
sudo modprobe pcspkr
sudo find /dev/ -mmin -1
/dev/ptmx
/dev/pts/5
/dev/pts/6

module is not used
lsmod |grep pcspkr
pcspkr                 12288  0

Trying echo -e '\a' or printf \a
give no sound.
There is a way to create a fake bell?
Thanks

Note that printf \a prints a but if you want a bell, you need printf \\a or printf '\a'

Yes, don't work also with this syntax, anyway I have edited my answer, thanks

Solution found, even I don't like the sound (but this can be fixed)
pactl upload-sample /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/bell.oga bell-window-system
pactl load-module module-x11-bell display=$DISPLAY

Now echo -e '\a' works
